# Adding data to datable from a dialog box - jsf - primefaces

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I'm having this problem of adding data to my datatable from a dialog box. I click on a commandButton "add", a dialog box should appear and then I should save the data entries, but when I check them I find them empty (datatable single row selection).

The code:

```
<p:commandButton process="singleDT" update=":form:add" icon="ui-icon-plus" value="Add"
    oncomplete="PF('addDialog').show()" />

<p:dataTable id="singleDT" var="o" value="#{UserBean.listE}" selectionMode="single"
    selection="#{UserBean.selectedEvent}" rowKey="#{o.id_event}">
    <p:column headerText="Id">
        <h:outputText value="#{o.id_event}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Event">
        <h:outputText value="#{o.event}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Date">
        <h:outputText value="#{o.date_event}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

The dialog box when the button "add" is clicked:

```
 <p:dialog header="Addevent" widgetVar="addDialog" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">
    <p:outputPanel id="ajouter" style="text-align:center;">

        <p:panelGrid  columns="2"  columnClasses="label,value">
         <h:outputText value="Id:" />
            <h:inputText value="#{id_event}" />

            <h:outputText value="Event" />
            <h:inputText value="#{event}" />

            <h:outputText value="Date " />
            <h:inputText value="#{date_event}" />
        </p:panelGrid>
       </p:outputPanel>
    <p:commandButton action="#{UserBean.Add}" icon="ui-icon-edit" value="Add"  />
```

The UserBean method `Add()`:

```
public void Add()
{
    System.out.println("adding");
    event e=new event();
    e.setId_event(id_event);
    e.setEvent(event);
    e.setDate_event(date_event);
    serviceevent.add(e);
    System.out.println("added to database ");
    listE= serviceevent.findAll();
    System.out.println("refrech ");
}
```

the stack error:

```
Hibernate: insert into event (date_event, etat_event, event) values (?, ?, ?)
juin 29, 2017 10:43:46 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
juin 29, 2017 10:43:46 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Le champ 'event' ne peut être vide (null)
juin 29, 2017 10:43:46 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
AVERTISSEMENT: #{UserBean.Ajouter}: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
javax.faces.FacesException: #{UserBean.Ajouter}: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2909)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3480)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:623)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:277)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:303)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:682)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:674)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:669)
    at com.ismo.gestionabsence.dao.eventDAOImpl.add(eventDAOImpl.java:19)
    at com.ismo.gestionabsence.services.eventservicesImpl.add(eventservicesImpl.java:19)
    at com.ismo.gestionabsence.presentation.UserBean.Ajouter(UserBean.java:331)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:279)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Le champ 'event' ne peut être vide (null)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2501)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2079)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2013)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5104)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1998)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:205)
    ... 60 more
```

[image: Image of the dialog box].

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

As per exception, the page is unable to proccess 'selectedEvent' because it is `null`.

You should instantiate it in `UserBean` before using it.

For example:

```
private SelectedEvent selectedEvent = new SelectedEvent();
```

Also, to see the changes in the datatable you need to use the update element in the command button.

```
<p:commandButton action="#{UserBean.Add}" icon="ui-icon-edit" value="Add" update="singleDT"  />
```

Regards

Comment: Thank you for answering , what  have is private event selectedEvent; with getters and setters .

Comment: The commandButton add should make appear the dialog box then save the entries from the dialog , but when ever i try to do so i can't get the values entred in the input fields , they are null . @MarcosViníciusSoares

Answer (score 0):

Okay the answer is simple , i wasn't drinking enought water lol , its the basics of jsf (silly post):

```
   <!-- dialog addevent -->
    <p:dialog header="Add event" widgetVar="addDialog" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">
    <p:outputPanel id="add" style="text-align:center;">

        <p:panelGrid  columns="2"  columnClasses="label,value">
         <h:outputText value="Id:" />
            <h:inputText value="#{UserBean.id_event}" />

            <h:outputText value="Event" />
            <h:inputText value="#{UserBean.event}" />

            <h:outputText value="Date " />
            <h:inputText value="#{UserBean.date_event}" />
        </p:panelGrid>
       </p:outputPanel>
    <p:commandButton action="#{UserBean.Add}" icon="ui-icon-edit" value="Save"  />
    <p:commandButton process="singleDT" update=":form:add" icon="ui-icon-
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: Posting just code without describing the differences/changes is not the best way of answering. Can you please improve it